# Returning the index on an element of a long array(a) from a method addTwo

Tags: java

```
public int[] addTwo(int target){

   long first = (int) a[0];
   int last = (int) a[a.length-1];
   int answer = (int) (first + last);
   for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {


       if(answer > target) {
           last = (int) a[a.length-1-i];
       }
       if(answer < target) {
           first = (int) a[0 + i];
       }
       if(answer == target) {

       }


   }
   return null;  // For compilation, you need to change it.
}
```

the method is supposed to find two numbers in the array which equals to the parameter. It is also part of a class which initializes a long array called a. In the statement line, if(answer == target), I am supposed to return the index of the two numbers which equal to the parameter. I can't seem to do so as the method requires a return of int[].

Comment: You are correct.  The return type is `int[]`, so you cannot return an `int`.  I suggest going back to your instructor and asking for clarification.

Comment: It looks like you're supposed to return an `int[]` of length 2, with the two elements being the two indexes of the parameter.